# If one does fidyah for not fasting in Ramadan, but afterwards one is able to fast, should one make up for missed days?

Tags: ramadan, sawm, sick, fidyah

If one is terminally ill, and:

- is unable to fast during the month of Ramadan, and
- it is not foreseeable at the time that one would be able to make up for missed days in the future,

It is agreed upon that one should do a [*fidyah*](https://islamqa.info/en/49944) by feeding one poor person an equivalent of what one normally eats for every day one is unable to fast.

If one then recovers after Ramadan and

- is able to fast, and
- is able to make up for missed days of Ramadan,

**Question:** With the days already being expiated for, should one still fast an equivalent number of days, or is the expiation enough at this stage?

I am interested in the Sunni view in general. If providing an answer that is madhhab-specific, please mention which madhhab the view belongs to, but views from any or all madhhabs are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>(This is what I found in the Ta'leemul Haq, a Hanafi based book on the five fundamental pillars of Islam)</sub>

The condition for Fidyah is:

> - A very old person who does **NOT** have the strength to fast or a very sickly or diseased person who has **NO** hope of recovering after Ramadan, should give **FIDYAH** for each fast missed in Ramadan.
>
> If, however, an old or sick person gains strength or recovers after Ramadan, he **MUST** keep the missed number of fasts and whatever was given as Fidyah will be a reward for him from Allah.

So according to this, one **should make up for these missed fasts.**

And Allah knows best.

---

Source: [Ta'leemul Haq, page 262 out of 321 on the PDF and page 150 in the actual book](http://islamicbulletin.org/free_downloads/resources/taleemul_haq.pdf)